# Finding the equation that meets certain requirements

Tags: functions

I am interested in finding a function that describes the following graph and satisfies a set of requirements.

---

First I will describe what is given:

1. An image of the graph (definitely easier to understand the problem if you see the image)

   - [Link to graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CEcB.jpg)

2) The constants $t$, $m$, and $h$

- $t$ is described as the minimum value of $f(x)$ which occurs at $x=m$

$0<=t<=1$
$t<=f(x)<=1$

- $m$ is described as the right bound of $x$

$1<=m<=+∞$
$0<=x<=m$

- $h$ is described as the $x$-value where $|f`(x)|$ is greatest.

$0<=h<=m$

---

The requirements are as follows:

1. $f(0)=1$
2. $f(m)=t$
3. The value of $|f`(x)|$ must be greatest at $x=h$

---

Here is what I have done so far:

- I found that the following equation describes the graph nicely:
  $$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}cot^{-1}(Ax+cot(3)), 0 <=x<=m$$
- $f`(x)$ is as follows:
  $$f`(x)=-\frac{A}{3((Ax+cot(3))^2+1}$$
- $f``(x)$, which has one root between $0$ and $m$, such that this root is at $(h, 0)$:
  $$f``(x)=\frac{2A^2(Ax+cot(3))}{3((Ax+cot(3))^2+1}$$
- Also concerning dealing with $h$, I found that $f(h)=t+\frac{1-t}{2}$, but this equality would need to be checked if $f(x)$ is changed. I also don't know if this even simplifies my problem!

I am stuck on how to incorporate the constants into my function equation! How can I incorporate the constants into $f(x)$ for any value of $t$, $m$, and $h$ within their respective bounds? Would it be easier to find a piece-wise function instead? Any thoughts on how to approach or solve this problem would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**: Ended up going piecewise and solved using these two quadratic functions. Although this doesn't necessarily describe the nature of the graph in the image...

$$f(x)=ax^2+1, {0<=x<=h}$$
$$a=\frac{\frac{t-1}{2}}{h^2}$$

$$g(x)=b(x-m)^2+t, {h<x<=m}$$
$$b=-\frac{\frac{t-1}{2}}{(h-m)^2}$$

---

This can also be somewhat solved, *without accounting for $h$*, as a function of $cos^2(x)$:

$$f(x)=(1-t)cos^2(\frac{\pi x}{2m})+t, 0<=x<=m$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to incorporate the constants t, m, and h into the equation for f(x) is to use the piecewise function definition. This allows you to define different expressions for f(x) depending on the value of x, which allows you to easily incorporate the given constraints on t, m, and h.

For example, you could define f(x) as follows:

if x < h, then f(x) = 1 - t * (x / h)
if x >= h, then f(x) = t + (1 - t) * (x - h) / (m - h)

This piecewise function satisfies the given constraints on t, m, and h, and it also matches the shape of the graph in the given image. To ensure that the derivative of f(x) has a root at x=h, you can choose the constant A in the equation for f'(x) to be the reciprocal of the slope of the line segment connecting the points (h, t) and (h, t + 1 - t^2).

Alternatively, you could try to find a single equation for f(x) that satisfies the given constraints and matches the shape of the graph. This might be more challenging, but it could potentially result in a simpler and more elegant expression for f(x).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I ended up going piecewise and solved it, but am definitely interested in trying to solve it in one function eventually :)